# App Store Distribution Certificate

Tags: ios, app-store, certificate

Can I test the .ipa file Locally which is build with App Store Distribution Certificate.When I export as IPA File and try to install the Build in Devices It says the following Error

Error: itunes Sync
       App failed to Install.

Comment: You can ask better questions if you understand this:  http://sscce.org

Comment: @NAZIK,Łukasz L.  **can u say what is wrong in the question**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The App store distribution certificate is for just that. The app is identical regardless of the certificate used to sign the build, so you can test using a development or ad hoc profile before creating the app store build with the App Store certificate.